# Swift generics *= operator error

Tags: generics, swift

I have the following simple struct type.

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit

protocol Named {
    class var name: String { get }
}

extension Float: Named {
    static var name: String { return "Float" }
}

struct Vector3<T: protocol<Named, FloatingPointType>>: Printable { // This protocol solves the generics issue
    // Properties
    var x, y, z: T
    var description: String {
        return "Vector3<\(T.name)>(\(x), \(y), \(z))"
    }
    // Methods - mutating
    mutating func factored(factor: T) {
        x *= factor
    }

}
```

I want to be able to take as a parameter to `factored` the same type the struct was created with. But this results with a `Cannot invoke *= with an argument list of type (T, T)`.

Do I need to implement the `*=` operator, along with any other I end up needing? How would I do that?

### Edit

After @matt gave a suggestion to just declare Vector3 as adhering to the `FloatingPointType` protocol it solved the issue. Though now I'm getting a `T is not identical to UInt8` inside the `factored` method.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is my issue. What would be the solution? Some protocol?

Comment: @matt thanks for catching that, just stated the same intention in the code comments, but didn't get around to it because of this generics issue.

Comment: Float, Int, Double. What do you have in mind? It'd be cool if you used the answer box :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

As per @matt's suggestion, combining the protocols probably makes the most sense here:

```
protocol NamedAndMultipliable {
    class var name: String { get }
    func *=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

func *=(inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int) {
    lhs = lhs * rhs
}

extension Int : NamedAndMultipliable {
    static var name: String { return "Int" }
}
extension Double : NamedAndMultipliable {
    static var name: String { return "Double" }
}
extension Float : NamedAndMultipliable {
    static var name: String { return "Float" }
}

struct Vector3<T: NamedAndMultipliable>: Printable {
    // Properties
    var x, y, z: T
    var description: String {
        return "Vector3<\(T.name)>(\(x), \(y), \(z))"
    }
    // Methods - mutating
    mutating func factored(factor: T) {
        x *= factor
    }   
}
```

**Original Answer**

I was able to get what I think you intend by doing the following:

```
protocol Named {
    class var name: String { get }
}

protocol Multipliable {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int : Multipliable {}
extension Double : Multipliable {}
extension Float : Multipliable {}

extension Int : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Int" }
}
extension Double : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Double" }
}
extension Float : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Float" }
}

struct Vector3<T: protocol<Named, Multipliable>>: Printable {
    // Properties
    var x, y, z: T
    var description: String {
        return "Vector3<\(T.name)>(\(x), \(y), \(z))"
    }
    // Methods - mutating
    mutating func factored(factor: T) {
        x = x * factor
    }

}
```

If you prefer to stick with the `*=` operator, you can do that, but if you want to support `Int` as well, you'll need to add a function for it.

```
protocol MultipliableIntoSelf {
    func *=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

func *=(inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int) {
    lhs = lhs * rhs
}

extension Int : MultipliableIntoSelf {}
extension Double : MultipliableIntoSelf {}
extension Float : MultipliableIntoSelf {}

protocol Named {
    class var name: String { get }
}

extension Int : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Int" }
}
extension Double : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Double" }
}
extension Float : Named {
    static var name: String { return "Float" }
}

struct Vector3<T: protocol<Named, MultipliableIntoSelf>>: Printable {
    // Properties
    var x, y, z: T
    var description: String {
        return "Vector3<\(T.name)>(\(x), \(y), \(z))"
    }
    // Methods - mutating
    mutating func factored(factor: T) {
        x *= factor
    }

}
```

Comment: What about the `*=` operator?

Comment: I added an example showing how to do that as well, I left it out only because I didn't want to add the function for `Int` which I think you want to support.  I don't think they have it declared in the system because it can automatically convert to `UInt8`, or `UInt16`, or whatever.  With generics though, it requires one to be more specific.

Comment: Actually, Multipliable is doing no work in that code. You can delete it and just specify that Named requires `func *`.

Comment: And at that point `protocol<Named>` is doing no work; you can just say `Named`.

Comment: @matt - I thought about that, but I felt it should have a separate protocol because `Named` doesn't imply that it will also have multipliable functionality.  The other option would be to change the name to something more inclusive of both, I just couldn't think of something good.

Comment: Well we could call it NamedNumber. :)

Comment: @matt - Correct w/ the `protocol<Named>` if the two were combined into one protocol, you wouldn't need that.

Comment: @matt - Went ahead and added that version as well :)  (It really does make the most sense!)

Comment: The problem at bottom, though, is that you'd have to add every possible operation this class might need. This is not a critique of your answer; it's a critique of Swift's annoying numerics system. It would be easier to make this a nongeneric and make everything a Double and just walk away. :(

Comment: @matt - I agree, it can get a bit tedious at times.

Answer (score -1):

This won't compile because there's no guarantee that your T type can be multiplied, or even assignable. You will have to implement/override the = and * operators for a Named type in order for this to work. I'm not sure whether protocols can even require implementation of an operator, though.